# reasoning from incomplete data

Tags: statistical-significance

https://yasp.co/distributions shows a chart with game ranking scores. 866824 players were measured out of a 12432671 population. Sampling was non-random, instead only those are counted who chose to share their ranking score publicly.

[image]

Are the percentiles and the average largely accurate compared to the results of a full census? If so, how can we know? Does the chart have validity with respect to reality, are those 7% enough? Is it as likely that the average is not near ~3200, but 1000 points lower?

Attaching extracted data in machine readable form for your convenience:

```
[{"bin":0,"bin_name":0,"count":547,"cumulative_sum":547},
{"bin":1,"bin_name":100,"count":320,"cumulative_sum":867},
{"bin":2,"bin_name":200,"count":401,"cumulative_sum":1268},
{"bin":3,"bin_name":300,"count":569,"cumulative_sum":1837},
{"bin":4,"bin_name":400,"count":821,"cumulative_sum":2658},
{"bin":5,"bin_name":500,"count":1048,"cumulative_sum":3706},
{"bin":6,"bin_name":600,"count":1317,"cumulative_sum":5023},
{"bin":7,"bin_name":700,"count":1710,"cumulative_sum":6733},
{"bin":8,"bin_name":800,"count":2116,"cumulative_sum":8849},
{"bin":9,"bin_name":900,"count":2618,"cumulative_sum":11467},
{"bin":10,"bin_name":1000,"count":3753,"cumulative_sum":15220},
{"bin":11,"bin_name":1100,"count":4248,"cumulative_sum":19468},
{"bin":12,"bin_name":1200,"count":4752,"cumulative_sum":24220},
{"bin":13,"bin_name":1300,"count":5483,"cumulative_sum":29703},
{"bin":14,"bin_name":1400,"count":6100,"cumulative_sum":35803},
{"bin":15,"bin_name":1500,"count":6936,"cumulative_sum":42739},
{"bin":16,"bin_name":1600,"count":7540,"cumulative_sum":50279},
{"bin":17,"bin_name":1700,"count":8501,"cumulative_sum":58780},
{"bin":18,"bin_name":1800,"count":9659,"cumulative_sum":68439},
{"bin":19,"bin_name":1900,"count":11157,"cumulative_sum":79596},
{"bin":20,"bin_name":2000,"count":14826,"cumulative_sum":94422},
{"bin":21,"bin_name":2100,"count":15564,"cumulative_sum":109986},
{"bin":22,"bin_name":2200,"count":17218,"cumulative_sum":127204},
{"bin":23,"bin_name":2300,"count":18776,"cumulative_sum":145980},
{"bin":24,"bin_name":2400,"count":21247,"cumulative_sum":167227},
{"bin":25,"bin_name":2500,"count":23178,"cumulative_sum":190405},
{"bin":26,"bin_name":2600,"count":24565,"cumulative_sum":214970},
{"bin":27,"bin_name":2700,"count":26612,"cumulative_sum":241582},
{"bin":28,"bin_name":2800,"count":28561,"cumulative_sum":270143},
{"bin":29,"bin_name":2900,"count":31426,"cumulative_sum":301569},
{"bin":30,"bin_name":3000,"count":43212,"cumulative_sum":344781},
{"bin":31,"bin_name":3100,"count":41027,"cumulative_sum":385808},
{"bin":32,"bin_name":3200,"count":40571,"cumulative_sum":426379},
{"bin":33,"bin_name":3300,"count":39265,"cumulative_sum":465644},
{"bin":34,"bin_name":3400,"count":38979,"cumulative_sum":504623},
{"bin":35,"bin_name":3500,"count":38387,"cumulative_sum":543010},
{"bin":36,"bin_name":3600,"count":35256,"cumulative_sum":578266},
{"bin":37,"bin_name":3700,"count":33525,"cumulative_sum":611791},
{"bin":38,"bin_name":3800,"count":31022,"cumulative_sum":642813},
{"bin":39,"bin_name":3900,"count":28304,"cumulative_sum":671117},
{"bin":40,"bin_name":4000,"count":39927,"cumulative_sum":711044},
{"bin":41,"bin_name":4100,"count":28572,"cumulative_sum":739616},
{"bin":42,"bin_name":4200,"count":24175,"cumulative_sum":763791},
{"bin":43,"bin_name":4300,"count":20060,"cumulative_sum":783851},
{"bin":44,"bin_name":4400,"count":17038,"cumulative_sum":800889},
{"bin":45,"bin_name":4500,"count":14578,"cumulative_sum":815467},
{"bin":46,"bin_name":4600,"count":10668,"cumulative_sum":826135},
{"bin":47,"bin_name":4700,"count":7962,"cumulative_sum":834097},
{"bin":48,"bin_name":4800,"count":5988,"cumulative_sum":840085},
{"bin":49,"bin_name":4900,"count":4482,"cumulative_sum":844567},
{"bin":50,"bin_name":5000,"count":7577,"cumulative_sum":852144},
{"bin":51,"bin_name":5100,"count":3525,"cumulative_sum":855669},
{"bin":52,"bin_name":5200,"count":2517,"cumulative_sum":858186},
{"bin":53,"bin_name":5300,"count":1799,"cumulative_sum":859985},
{"bin":54,"bin_name":5400,"count":1345,"cumulative_sum":861330},
{"bin":55,"bin_name":5500,"count":1157,"cumulative_sum":862487},
{"bin":56,"bin_name":5600,"count":744,"cumulative_sum":863231},
{"bin":57,"bin_name":5700,"count":587,"cumulative_sum":863818},
{"bin":58,"bin_name":5800,"count":446,"cumulative_sum":864264},
{"bin":59,"bin_name":5900,"count":352,"cumulative_sum":864616},
{"bin":60,"bin_name":6000,"count":690,"cumulative_sum":865306},
{"bin":61,"bin_name":6100,"count":308,"cumulative_sum":865614},
{"bin":62,"bin_name":6200,"count":232,"cumulative_sum":865846},
{"bin":63,"bin_name":6300,"count":175,"cumulative_sum":866021},
{"bin":64,"bin_name":6400,"count":154,"cumulative_sum":866175},
{"bin":65,"bin_name":6500,"count":112,"cumulative_sum":866287},
{"bin":66,"bin_name":6600,"count":83,"cumulative_sum":866370},
{"bin":67,"bin_name":6700,"count":77,"cumulative_sum":866447},
{"bin":68,"bin_name":6800,"count":66,"cumulative_sum":866513},
{"bin":69,"bin_name":6900,"count":54,"cumulative_sum":866567},
{"bin":70,"bin_name":7000,"count":96,"cumulative_sum":866663},
{"bin":71,"bin_name":7100,"count":58,"cumulative_sum":866721},
{"bin":72,"bin_name":7200,"count":22,"cumulative_sum":866743},
{"bin":73,"bin_name":7300,"count":23,"cumulative_sum":866766},
{"bin":74,"bin_name":7400,"count":15,"cumulative_sum":866781},
{"bin":75,"bin_name":7500,"count":9,"cumulative_sum":866790},
{"bin":76,"bin_name":7600,"count":9,"cumulative_sum":866799},
{"bin":77,"bin_name":7700,"count":4,"cumulative_sum":866803},
{"bin":78,"bin_name":7800,"count":3,"cumulative_sum":866806},
{"bin":79,"bin_name":7900,"count":3,"cumulative_sum":866809},
{"bin":80,"bin_name":8000,"count":10,"cumulative_sum":866819},
{"bin":81,"bin_name":8100,"count":1,"cumulative_sum":866820},
{"bin":82,"bin_name":8200,"count":2,"cumulative_sum":866822},
{"bin":84,"bin_name":8400,"count":1,"cumulative_sum":866823},
{"bin":88,"bin_name":8800,"count":1,"cumulative_sum":866824}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Responses seem to be anonymous, so chances are a little bit better that the scores are closer to the true mean. But nevertheless, 7% is a very low response rate and answers are likely to be skewed towards those who want to share their superior performance. And the only way to test that would be to sub-sample a truly random population.